# Remove columns that have 'N' number of NA values in it - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

Suppose I use df.isnull().sum() and I get a count for all the 'NA' values in all the columns of df dataframe. I want to remove a column that has NA values above 'K'.

For eg.,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2.1, np.nan, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8],
                'B': [0, np.nan, np.nan, 0, 0, 0],
                'C': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0],
                'D': [5, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 5.6, 6.8],
                'E': [0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],})
df.isnull().sum()

A    1
B    2
C    0
D    2
E    5
dtype: int64
```

Suppose I want to remove columns that have '2' and above number of NA values. How would be approach this problem? My output should be,

```
df.columns
A,C
```

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry do you mean `NaN` or the string 'NA'? Also your desired output does not match your data and explanation of what the desired result should be

Comment: @EdChum Sorry about that. My bad. I am meaning NaN values. I will change the DF now.

Comment: @EdChum Sorry again for the confusion. Have changed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and pass `axis=1` to drop column-wise and pass `thresh=len(df)-K`, what `thresh` does is it sets the minimum number of non-NaN values which is equal to the number of rows minus K NaN values

```
In [22]:

df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=len(df)-1)
Out[22]:
     A  C
0  1.0  0
1  2.1  0
2  NaN  0
3  4.7  0
4  5.6  0
5  6.8  0
```

If you just want the columns:

```
In [23]:
df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=len(df)-1).columns

Out[23]:
Index(['A', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

Or simply mask the counts output against the columns:

```
In [28]:
df.columns[df.isnull().sum() <2]

Out[28]:
Index(['A', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like:

```
df = df.reindex(columns=[x for x in df.columns.values if df[x].isnull().sum() < threshold])
```

Which just builds a list of columns that match your requirement (fewer than threshold nulls), and then uses that list to reindex the dataframe.  So if you set threshold to 1:

```
threshold = 1
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2.1, np.nan, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8],
            'B': [0, np.nan, np.nan, 0, 0, 0],
            'C': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0],
            'D': [5, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 5.6, 6.8],
            'E': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'],})
df = df.reindex(columns=[x for x in df.columns.values if df[x].isnull().sum() < threshold])
df.count()
```

Will yield:

```
C    6
E    6
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dropna()` function has a `thresh` argument that allows you to give the number of non-NaN values you require, so this would give you your desired output:

```
df.dropna(axis=1,thresh=5).count()

A    5
C    6
E    6
```

If you wanted just C & E, you'd have to change thresh to 6 in this case.